# Microsoft SQL MAX() Not Including Rows with NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, max

I work in a law firm with a case management system which links an interface to a SQL db.  I am writing queries in SSRS to run reports.  I am trying to run a report on case information.  Some of the information is right in the "cases" table (or vcases view), but I'm also trying to link information from a "demands_offers" table.  Each case can have multiple demands and offers, so I am using a MAX function in a join to extract only the most recent demand record per case.  Unfortunately, doing this eliminates cases which have no demands.  I need all the cases to show up.

I have tried using a CASE statement nested in the MAX function to convert NULLS or empty fields to a random early date, but I still can't get all of the cases to appear in the report.

Any ideas?  I am a relative newbie with SQL and have no formal training.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  You can see the code below.  (P.S. I don't think that I have the rights to create a temporary table.)

```
SELECT vc.case_number AS "Matter ID", vc.style, vc.atty2_name AS "Handling Attorney", m.max_demands_date, do.demands, do.demands_notes, sa.authorized,      
(SELECT TOP 1 vl.computename        
FROM vcases vca     
LEFT OUTER JOIN case_parties cp     
ON vca.case_sk = cp.case_sk     
JOIN case_parties cpp       
ON cp.parent_sk = cpp.case_parties_sk       
JOIN vlegal_entity vl       
ON vl.legal_entity_sk = cp.entity_sk        
JOIN vlegal_entity vlp      
ON vlp.legal_entity_sk = cpp.entity_sk      
WHERE (vca.case_sk = vc.case_sk) AND (cpp.role_sk = '3557') AND (cp.role_sk = '3986') ) AS "Plaintiff//'s Attorney",        
(SELECT cp.reference_number     
    FROM cases AS ca    
        LEFT OUTER JOIN case_parties AS cp
        ON ca.case_sk = cp.case_sk
    WHERE (cp.role_sk = '3706')     
        AND (ca.case_sk = vc.case_sk)) AS "Claim Number"


FROM        
vcases vc       
LEFT OUTER JOIN     
case_parties cp ON vc.case_sk = cp.case_sk      
LEFT OUTER JOIN     
vlegal_entity vl ON cp.entity_sk = vl.legal_entity_sk       
LEFT OUTER JOIN     
settle_authority sa ON vc.case_sk = sa.case_sk      
LEFT OUTER JOIN         
demands_offers do ON vc.case_sk = do.case_sk        

INNER JOIN      
 (SELECT DISTINCT max(
(CASE WHEN do.demands_date = '' THEN '1/1/1900 00:00:00'
             ELSE do.demands_date
              END)
  ) as "max_demands_date", vc.case_sk       
   FROM vcases AS vc        
   JOIN demands_offers AS do ON vc.case_sk = do.case_sk     
   GROUP BY vc.case_sk) AS m        
  ON vc.case_sk = m.case_sk  AND        
  do.demands_date = m.max_demands_date      

WHERE (vc.closed_ind = 'O') AND (cp.role_sk = '3816') AND (vl.client_number = 'EAS-01') AND (vc.lawtype_code <> 'FA')       
ORDER BY vc.case_number
```

Comment: Well, the behavior of `max()` **is** to ignore `null` values. Also, `null` and `''` are different (unless you're using Oracle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can probably be written to be much more compact and better performing, but to start you off, this is the part that is removing the rows without demands:

```
INNER JOIN      
 (SELECT DISTINCT max(
(CASE WHEN do.demands_date = '' THEN '1/1/1900 00:00:00'
             ELSE do.demands_date
              END)
  ) as "max_demands_date", vc.case_sk       
   FROM vcases AS vc        
   JOIN demands_offers AS do ON vc.case_sk = do.case_sk     
   GROUP BY vc.case_sk) AS m        
  ON vc.case_sk = m.case_sk  AND        
  do.demands_date = m.max_demands_date
```

It needs to be

```
LEFT JOIN      
 (SELECT DISTINCT max(
(CASE WHEN do.demands_date = '' THEN '1/1/1900 00:00:00'
             ELSE do.demands_date
              END)
  ) as "max_demands_date", vc.case_sk       
   FROM vcases AS vc        
   JOIN demands_offers AS do ON vc.case_sk = do.case_sk     
   GROUP BY vc.case_sk) AS m        
  ON vc.case_sk = m.case_sk  AND        
  do.demands_date = m.max_demands_date
```

The reason is that an `(A INNER JOIN B)` keeps records only when it is possible to match rows in A to rows in B.  When there is no demand, the derived table (subquery) returns NULL for `max_demands_date`, which cannot be matched by `do.demands_date = m.max_demands_date`.  This causes the `case` record to get removed.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!  I knew that I was missing something really simple.  Thank you for explaining the logic too.  That helped me understand the "why" and how to avoid the same problem in the future (and/or recreate the problem on purpose when I need that kind of result).  Most of my SQL knowledge comes from the Visual Quickstart Guide, MSDN.com and various forums.  If you know of a good class, please feel free to send or post the information.  Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I just started working on an introduction to JOINs. It is a series of blog post, one every day during this month. You can find them here http://sqlity.net/en/1146/a-join-a-day-introduction/